# React Native: How to pull a defined list of dates and export them into a ListView

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am building an app that lets users capture past meetings and I need to generate a list of days (today + seven days before, excluding weekends).

I am seeking advice as to how I would go about doing this and then exporting it to a ListView in React Native. Should I do it on the Redux side?

A sample of how the days should display are below - assuming today is Tuesday:

```
- Today
- Yesterday
- Friday
- Thursday
- Wednesday
- Tuesday
- Monday
- Last Friday
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list of days relative to today by using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library. I guess you will need to check these API sections:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

For example, if you want to get last week Friday, and today is Tuesday, you would go with something like:

```
moment().subtract(4, 'days');
```

You can create a helper function which returns a day name relative to today, and then in your component, you call the function. I think that will keep it clear.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out!